# The function is called twice when the surface is touched

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment with touchable or clickable layout, i do not know why when i touch the fragment's layout and left my finger the funtion ""retrieveMQTTConnAssets()"" is caled twice "once when i touch the surface and keep touching and second time when i left my finger"

pease et  meknow hw to avoid such behavior.

**Update**:

Actuay, I solved it now by instead of returning true, i returned false.but i do not understand it, why it is like this.

**code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.w(TAG, "@onCreateView()");
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eco_frag, container, false);
    root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "toched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            retrieveMQTTConnAssets();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simple, and it is that

```
root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //this is called, right?
        retrieveMQTTConnAssets();
        return true;
    }
});
```

in `onTouch`, you receive a parameter called `MotionEvent`. That `MotionEvent` stores something called `action`, which can have many values (see [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)), but most importantly `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

If you want to make it so that it runs only when you release it, then you should check for that type of action.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        retrieveMQTTConnAssets();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I came to say that. To explain a bit more: `ACTION_DOWN` is when the user starts touching the screen and `ACTION_UP` is when the user stops touching the screen